# Accelerometer sample projects

Tags: iphone

I want some accelerometer sample projects through which i can understand how i can move my object by moving iPhone or iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BubbleLevel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BubbleLevel/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007331) from apple

And here is the [UIAccelerometer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html)